# Migrate all users of my paid app to in-app purchase

Tags: android, google-play

Actually, I have 2 apps : free and paid (pro version).
I would like to migrate my 2 apps to a free app with an in-app-purchases.

Can I save all the people how have paid the pro version in my in-app-purchases ?
What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to be handled logically.
1) Simply launch the in- app purchase version of App for everyone.
2) Put a simple check whether user has paid the pro version already (must be somewhere saved on your server side) 
If Yes - allow him the in app purchase benefits
Else They will be shown In App purchase options.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do as a workaround is to make an update to the pro version to remove all functionality and use it as a “unlock app” for the pro functions in your free app by checking if the old “pro app” exists for legacy users. This way you don’t have to migrate anything. The old users are this way still able to reinstall the old app and use it  as an unlock app. The downside of this is that the old PRO app could still be purchased.

EDIT: This has actually been done before. SD Maid uses this as their main way of getting the pro version of the app.

Link to google play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm&hl=nl

Answer (score 1):

> Actually, I have 2 apps : free and paid (pro version). I would like to
>   migrate my 2 apps to a free app with an in-app-purchases.
>
> Can I save all the people how have paid the pro version in my
>   in-app-purchases ? What is the best way to do that ?

There are number of ways with prons and cons:

1)You can manage with two app and at Free app show Pro version features and If user want Pro Features then move to play store for download.

So due to this you will no loss Free app users.

2)single app with Pro Version so no need to manage both apps.