# Switch all users of my paid Android app to in-app purchase without taking money from people who have already bought it

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I want to convert my paid app to a free one with in-app purchase without creating a new app and without taking money from people who have already purchased it.

I am currently thinking about the following: Include the `License Verification Library` to check if someone has purchased the app. If so, the person gets the free upgrade. My question is if Google also responds with [LICENSED](https://github.com/google/play-licensing/blob/89ebdfcf52562018ff4c366055f0e35393919763/lvl_library/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/licensing/LicenseValidator.java#L39) if the app has been converted to free and someone installs it the first time (new user, not bought it in the past). In this case, would Google also return `LICENSED`? Because if not, that way we could filter out the people who bought the app before and offer the in-app purchase to everyone else.

Unfortunately this is not really documented, the most detailed I found is the following:

> The application is licensed to the user. The user has purchased the application, or is authorized to download and install the alpha or beta version of the application.

From https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/licensing-reference#lvl-summary

I am aware that it is kind of a duplicate of [Migrate all users of my paid app to in-app purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188968/migrate-all-users-of-my-paid-app-to-in-app-purchase), but in the meantime, hopefully there is a better workaround.